# Isomorphism of categories from Group(Set/I) to Grp^I?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, set-theory

Since this is a long exposition, I labeled the actual "questions" (1) and (2) ("(*)" is to make a reference).

Let I be a set (for our purposes it will be, informally stated, an "indexing set"). I think there is a somewhat natural functor from Groups(Set/I) (where Set/I is the slice category) to the functor category Grp^I, so I am (*) taking I to be the discrete category here (constructing the functor was an exercise in Steven Awodey's CT book ch.4, I don't that is the part I need help with, and yes this is recreational), namely, let's say that $G:X\to I$ is an object in Group(Set/I) (I think we would also say "G is a group object in Set/I", right?). Here is part of my proving the functor exists for context sake (I think the way I constructed it here it is also faithful):

[image]

My full proof is somewhat long (maybe 4 pages to get the functor) but I ended up getting that $X\times X$ = $\sqcup_{i\in I}(G^{-1}(i)\times G^{-1}(i))$ and we have a functor F so that F takes $G:X\to I$ to the functor $F_G:I\to Grp$ where $F_G(i) = G^{-1}(i)$ (the details of why these are groups I don't think are that difficult, and I think I understand, roughly stated, when you restrict the diagrams for the axioms of a group object in Set/I to $G^{-1}(i)$ instead of X, you get what it means for $G^{-1}(i)$ to be a group in Set, so I am not going to focus more on that here). Since I is discrete (c.f. (*) ), $F_G$ is really just the I-indexed family: $\{G^{-1}(i) : i\in I\}$. I was told that there is an "isomorphism" functor, namely this one I think (in the sense of having a two-sided inverse functor), and it would be totally natural but I am stuck on the fact that we sent G to an I-indexed family of $\textit{disjoint}$ groups. I could settle for an equivalence of categories, but I wanted to ask if this would work perhaps: Take an I-indexed family of groups H = $\{H_i : i\in I\}$. I am going to take for granted an isomorphism $\Phi$ from $Grp^I$ to the category of I-indexed groups, call it $(Grp,I)$, to not bog this down farther. I want to prove that H is isomorphic to an I-indexed family of disjoint groups K = $\{K_i : i\in I\}$. I think we can just simply "re-label" the $H_i$ so that they are pairwise disjoint, but (1):

I am not sure if this is rigorous: can we use the axiom of choice [AC] as follows? Pick an $i^* \in I$ and we will leave $K_{i^*}:= H_{i^*}$ then by the well-ordering principle (the one that's equivalent to AC) well order I (re-choose $i^*$ if it is not already the minimum). Then, by way of transfinite induction, if we have constructed $K_j$, Form a set $S_{j+1}$ disjoint from $H_{r}$ for $r\leq j$, and with cardinality greater than every $H_i$, take $H_{\hat{s}}$ to be a generating set for $H_s$ $\forall s\in I$ (I think we can do this since $H_{\hat{s}}$ can be $H_s$ if nothing else) and define $K_{j+1}$ by (injectively) mapping each $h\in H_{\hat{s}}$ to an element of $S_{j+1}$ (Then take $K_{j+1}:= <Im(H_{\widehat{j+1}})>$). If I is countable, I think we are done. If not, assume we have constructed $K_{\lambda}$ for an ordinal $\lambda$ (s.t. $\exists \delta\in I$, $\delta > \lambda$), construct $S_{\lambda +1}$ (again, with cardinality greater than every $H_i$) disjoint from $\cup_{i\leq \lambda}H_i$ and (injectively) map a generating set of $H_{\lambda + 1}$ into $S_{\lambda + 1}$ to construct $K_{\lambda + 1}$. Then I think we have $K_i\cong H_i$ $\forall i\in I$ (since it is just a relabeling with the same operation). If that is all correct (which is mainly what I am unsure about), then I think, for the inverse functor, we can just send the family $\{H_i :i\in I\}$ to $\sqcup_{i\in I}K_i$.

(2): Am I at least correct that such an isomorphism exists?

Comment: If you want a strict isomorphism it is probably better to work with $\textbf{Grp} (\textbf{Set}^I)$ instead – then you don't have to invoke the axiom of choice. AC is not needed if you will settle for an equivalence. I think the cardinalities do happen to work out so that there is an isomorphism anyway (if you assume AC, or maybe something stronger) but that's somehow just a coincidence.